# Get first free number from column

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2, hql

I would like to get first number from column.

In column i have numbers:

1
2
3
4
6
8

So the first free number is: 5 
Insert 5 to this column 
The second call should return: 7
insert 7 to this column 
Another call should return: 9
[...]

I know how to write this SQL, but the problem is that, this column is chart type. 
So its possible to be like this:

1
2
3
a
b
c
7
8
9

This is also not problem, i can use some isNumeric function to filtered records, but i should do this in HQL.

My idea is something like this:

SELECT distinct min(value) FROM table WHERE number+1 NOT IN (SELECT charColumn  FROM table)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aware how to write this in SQL, using one of following ways you can do achieve this by using hibernate.

1. You can directly write the native sql query in hibernate by using createSqlQuery() method of session.
   Refer this URL for more details; http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html
2. **OR -** Make a view of your Sql query and call it from your code by binding it with your entity class.